Is it safe to define a variable and use it in an other `:=` before the `return`?
I remember reading somewhere that XPath could potentially process the components of an expression in //; so my question is: Can I define a variable and use it in an other variable definition of the same let expression before the return? For example:
let
    $a := //abc,
    $x := $a/xyz
return
    $x

Or do I have to write, to be on the safe side:
let $a := //abc return
let $x := $a/xyz return
$x


The rules depend on which version of XPath you are using.
XPath 1.0 and 2.0 do not have a "let" expression.
XPath 3.0 and 3.1 allow let $a :=1, $b := 2 return $a+$b and they allow let $a :=1 return let $b := 2 return $a+$b but they do not allow let $a :=1 let $b := 2 return $a+$b. The draft XPath 4.0 proposal allows all these forms (as do all versions of XQuery).

Is there a definite behavior regarding which one of $a := 1 and $b := 2 should be evaluated first in let $a = 1, $b := 2?

If the value of $b depends on $a, then obviously $a has to be evaluated first. But if there's no dependency, the optimizer is allowed to do anything it likes to change the order of execution. It's common practice for variables to be evaluated lazily, which means the value isn't computed until it is needed.
